# Facebook for Android 3.0 log in

Tags: android, facebook

I went through the [tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/login-with-facebook/) and successfully implemented the log in and log out flow. However this works with the built-in login button:

```
  <com.facebook.widget.LoginButton
        android:id="@+id/authButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        />
```

When the user selects eg. an item from a list, a custom dialog appears with a Share option. When the user selects this Share option, I want to log in them to facebook and the usual stuff like ABC would like to access your profile, ABC would like to post to your friends etc.

Edit:
I guess I have found [what I need](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/share-dialog), but I ran into a problem early. I cannot import `FacebookDialog`. Neither is it offered to me, nor can I use when I import `com.facebook.*;`

According to [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/FacebookDialog.ShareDialogBuilder/) `FacebookDialog` is in the `com.facebook.widget` package. However when I type `import com.facebook.widget`. the only dialog that is offered is the `WebDialog`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I needed was the [Feed dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/feed-dialog/).

Example:

```
private void publishFeedDialog() {
    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("name", "New level!");
    params.putString("description", "I have reached level " + lvel!");
    params.putString("link", "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.myapp");
    params.putString("picture", "http://myapp.com/Images/icoon.png");

        WebDialog feedDialog = (
                new WebDialog.FeedDialogBuilder(this,
                    Session.getActiveSession(),
                    params))
                .setOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(Bundle values,
                        FacebookException error) {
                         if (error == null) {
                                // When the story is posted, echo the success
                                // and the post Id.
                                final String postId = values.getString("post_id");
                                if (postId != null) {
                                    //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Posted story, id: "+postId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                } else {
                                    // User clicked the Cancel button
                                    //Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Publish cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            } else if (error instanceof FacebookOperationCanceledException) {
                                // User clicked the "x" button
                                //Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Publish cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            } else {
                                // Generic, ex: network error
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                                    "Error sharing app",  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                    }

                })
                .build();
            feedDialog.show();
}
```